# find the docs page for function "in"

Tags: python

i'm trying to find the docs for the function

```
in
```

Inside python. It is very hard because the search engine can't function with a word like in.

Comment: It is not a function... it is only a built in keyword... search for for loops...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"`in`" is not a function. Its a built-in keyword. Using it can trigger the target objects `__contains__()`

[http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**contains**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

```
>>> l = ['a']
>>> l.__contains__('a')
True
>>> 'a' in l
True
```

I say "can trigger" because the logic has different ways it might resolve under the hood:

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test
>   first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration
>   protocol via `__getitem__()`

Note that this example only covers a membership test, as opposed to using it to loop over an iterable.

To illustrate how `in` is resolved during a loop operation, an iterator is first looked for using `__iter__()` :

```
l = range(5)
l.__iter__()
# <listiterator object at 0x1004e4fd0>
it = l.__iter__()
it.next()
# 0
it.next()
# 1
it.next()
# 2
```

In the event that the object does not have an `__iter__()` defined, it will try using the older `__getitem__()`. Take a string, for instance, which does not have an `__iter__()`. This is just an illustration...

```
>>> i = 0
>>> s = "string"
>>> while i < len(s):
...  print s.__getitem__(i)
...  i+=1
... 
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

And to show a similar iterator (generator here):

```
gen = (s.__getitem__(i) for i in xrange(len(s)))
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004e8780>
gen.next()
# 's'
gen.next()
# 't'
gen.next()
# 'r'
```

Comment: it can trigger, or does  it trigger 100%?

Answer (score 4):

For the use of `in` that results in a boolean, see http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details .  You can also use `in` in a couple of different ways in the form `for item in collection`, information for which is available on the same page.

The internal mechanics of the `in` operator are detailed on this page: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html -- the gist of it is that objects that support it need to provide the `__contains__()` method for the boolean usage and I think `__iter__()`  for the `for item in collection` usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called "[`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=contains#object.__contains__)".